# Limit of a piecewise function from $\mathbb{R}^2_{\ne0} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine if the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2_{\ne0} \to \mathbb{R}$ has a limit at the origin, when $$f(x,y) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       x^2, & x<0 \\
>       |y|, & x =0, y\ne0 \\
>       -y^2, & x >0 \\
> \end{array} 
> \right.$$

How should I do this with piecewise functions? Usually with these it helps to look at $x=0$ and $y=0$ seperately, but that didn't work here. Any hints?

Comment: *Hint:* $|f(x, y)| \le x^2 + y^2 + |y|$ for all $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta:=\epsilon$ (wlog assume $\epsilon<1$).

Then for the Euclidean norm $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta=\epsilon$, $$x<0\implies |f(x,y)|=|x^2|<\delta^2=\epsilon^2<\epsilon$$
$$ x=0\implies |f(x,y)|=|y|<\delta=\epsilon$$
$$x>0\implies |f(x,y)|=|y^2|<\delta^2=\epsilon^2<\epsilon$$

In any case $|f(x,y)|<\epsilon$. So $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: For the sake of completeness you should clarify which norm is used at $|(x,y)|<\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0^-,0)} f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0^-,0)} x^2=0$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0^+,0)} f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0^+,0)} -y^2=0$$

$$\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)=\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)} |y|=0$$

therefore the limit is equal to zero.